# HTML 505 on visit to page (PHP)

Tags: php

I am getting error 505 when I try to run my PHP page. It's saying unexpected $EOF at the end where `</html>` is. I've took away elements and added them back. Here's my code.

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$dir = "videos/".$user."/";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if (!file_exists($dir)) {

mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"pictures/".$user."/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>File Upload Progress Bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="bar_blank">
   <div id="bar_color"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="status"></div>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" 
id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hidden_iframe">
       <input type="hidden" value="myForm"
    name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
   <input type="file" name="userfile">
   <input type="submit" value="Start Upload">
  </form>
  <iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" src="blank.html"> 
   </iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am using PHP 7.0.

Comment: Count your }. I think, one is missing

Comment: @kuh-chan is right. One of your if statements is unclosed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed all of your `if` condition block. Try indenting the code, that will point these kind of errors

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {

    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    $dir = "videos/".$user."/";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if (!file_exists($dir)) {

          mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
       }
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'] . 
       ['tmp_name'],"pictures/".$user."/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
    }
<< ---- Missing closing ----->>
?>
```

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {

    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    $dir = "videos/".$user."/";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if (!file_exists($dir)) {

          mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
       }
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'] . 
       ['tmp_name'],"pictures/".$user."/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: is there anything else wrong with my code though? when I press submit it don't put anything in the user's folder.

Comment: Sorry, my PHP is bit rusty now; but I can see you create the `$dir` but you don't use it. Instead uses a `pictures/`. Is this exist?

Comment: The dir is being created now since I fixed that, but the file is not being uploaded for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, but where are you using that dir? It's not referenced on the `move_uploaded_file` line.